# Tensorflow Simple Model to Function

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I have a TensorFlow model that's been trained on some simple linear (y=3x+2) regression data, and when I plot it with matplotlib it looks like a straight line.

I would like to know what the *neural network* thinks about this problem.  For example, my neural network might think that the solution is `y=2.99x+2.01`.  How could I get this formula?

REASON:
I built a neural network that generates some pretty pictures when having it underfit a huge dataset.  I would like to get the underlying algebraic formula and translate it to C code if possible.

Comment: Bump...... I have a simple linear regression model, and I would like to extract it's formula..... help please!

Comment: Edited to make more sense, I hope @Community takes a look!

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you have plotted the Predicted Values using MatplotLib and you got a Straight Line, it should look something like shown below.

[image]

Goal is to calculate **m** (Weight Coefficient) and **c** (Bias) from the equation,

`y = m * x + c`, given the below Graph.

If you observe, there are 2 Rectangles formed using Green Lines. You can draw one for your plot.

X-Axis Coordinate and Y-Axis Coordinate for the Smaller Rectangle are 
`(x1, y1) = (0.35, 1.3)` (approx) and those for the Bigger Rectangle, 
`(x2, y2) = (0.65, 1.9)` (approx).

The **Slope** or **Coefficient** of the Line, `**m**` can be calculated using the Formula,

```
m = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)

m = (1.9-1.3)/(0.65-0.35) = 1.6/0.3 = 5.333.
```

If you see, the Red Line is Starting at around 0.95 (approx), in the Y-Axis. So, the **Bias** or **Intercept**, **`c`** is 0.95 (approx).

So, the equation in this case can be y = 5.333 * x + 0.95